# No breadcrumbs or trail in order to return to questions page

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, design

If I filter the questions, maybe based on tag, then go into a question, maybe post an answer, I have to use back button to get back to the list of questions based on my filter? I don't see another way. I remember on ebay, you can click around w/in items, and there's always the breadcrumb trail to get back to your original list of items so you can keep browsing.

Comment: You could always open the question in a new browser window/tab.  ... but I understand your point.

Comment: Wow, bit of a brain fart I didn't think of that. But yea, gotta get in that habit, kind of annoying.

Comment: I don't think this is going to change any time soon, but if you are still concerned about this we can migrate this to MSO.